# sending email using xampp

Tags: php, windows, email, xampp

Can I send an email using `XAMPP` ? Currently I am running `Mercury` in `XAMPP` as the mail server.

I want to test an application on my laptop that is required to send an email after 2 hours. I have been trying to send an email using the `mail` function but I don't get any.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu What else I need to do except starting `mercury` from the `xampp` control panel

Comment: You should be using a dedicated mailing-library [1][2] instead of php's mail function to send emails. Also, you should be using a verified account (gmail SMTP for example) or else your email will probably be marked as spam.

[1] http://swiftmailer.org/
[2] http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Answer (score 0):

*i think this will help:*

Edit your php.ini (xampp\php\php.ini). Search for [mail function]  and change these parameters accordingly.

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = [your_gmail_username]@gmail.com
Note: this gmail account will be used to send the email
sendmail_path = “\”D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\” -t”
```

Note: I did install my `xampp at D:\xampp`
Edit your `sendmail.ini (xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini)`
Comment the `“Mercury”  and “A free mail service example”` contents as shown below:

```
# Mercury
#account Mercury
#host localhost
#from postmaster@localhost
#auth off

# A freemail service example
#account Hotmail
#tls on
#tls_certcheck off
#host smtp.live.com
#from [exampleuser]@hotmail.com
#auth on
#user [exampleuser]@hotmail.com
#password [examplepassword]
```

1. Add the account through which you want to send your mails. In my example I have configured the Gmail account as shown below:

   account Gmail
       tls on
       tls_certcheck off
       host smtp.gmail.com
       from [your_gmail_username]@gmail.com
       auth on
       user [your_gmail_username]@gmail.com
       password [your_gmail_password]

   port 587
2. Set the default account to Gmail as shown below:

   account default : Gmail

code from [here](http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/)